# commit is not accessible using TortoiseGit Daemon

Tags: git, repository, daemon, git-branch, tortoisegit

This is how I share the changes in our local branch without pushing to remote-repository.

Steps to share a new added file or changes in repository:

1. select a project and create a branch on it.

   **TortoiseGit > Create Branch**

[image]

[image]

2. then switch to newly created branch.

   **TortoiseGit > Switch/Checkout**

[image]

[image]

3. inside the project make any changes to an existing file or add new file.

[image]

4. commit the changes to newly created branch.

   **Git Commit > new branch**

[image]

**Select and check** the file that were modified or newly created and **Commit**.

[image]

5. to share it to local repository and to make it to visible with-out pushing it to remote-repository or remote-origin. **TortoiseGit > Daemon**

   [image]
   [image]
6. check-out the branch by git clone and use the **git://< ip address >/< branch >**. in our case we create the test_branch so the url looks like this **git://10.192.20.140/test_branch**

   [image]
   [image]

now, my question is. why is it that when i clone that daemon branch it will then throw an exception of?

[image]

Comment: Does the hidden part of `--base-path=...` end with `\test_branch`?

Comment: @ElpieKay how do i make it visible to my local repository?

Comment: I have tried `git daemon` only via the command-line before. If I want to share `D:\init\test_branch`, test_branch is a git repo, I run `git daemon --export-all --base-path="D:\init\` at the server, and then run `git clone git://server_ip/test_branch` at the client side.

Comment: @ElpieKay yeah i can do a git daemon, but my problem is i cannot even checkout the changes in the branch i created. it will throw an exception of                 git.exe clone --progress -v "git://10.192.20.140/job-scheduler" "D:\init\project\job-scheduler"

Cloning into 'D:\init\project\job-scheduler'...
fatal: unable to connect to 10.192.20.140:
10.192.20.140[0: 10.192.20.140]: errno=Invalid argument



git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (21297 ms @ 5/31/2016 3:22:03 PM)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. job-scheduler should be a git repo. If it's a branch, it should be `-b job-scheduler` as an option of `git clone`

Comment: @ElpieKay sorry job-scheduler is my project that i want to share and use the command **git daemon** in order to do so. but my problem here is i cannot check-out using the command **git clone git://10.192.20.140/d/init/project//job-scheduler** and it will throw the exception of

Comment: git.exe clone --progress -v "git://10.192.20.140/job-scheduler" "D:\init\project\job-scheduler"

Cloning into 'D:\init\project\job-scheduler'...
fatal: unable to connect to 10.192.20.140:
10.192.20.140[0: 10.192.20.140]: errno=Invalid argument



git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (21328 ms @ 5/31/2016 5:29:12 PM)

Comment: since you set `--base-path` as `D:\init\xxx\, when you run `git clone git://10.192.20.140/d/init/project/job-scheduler`, it would try to clone from `D:\init\xxx\d\init\project\job-scheduler`, which cannot be found.

Comment: @ElpieKay yeah i tried also this command but got the same exception  **git clone git://10.192.20.140/job-scheduler**
Cloning into 'job-scheduler'...
fatal: unable to connect to 10.192.20.140:
10.192.20.140[0: 10.192.20.140]: errno=Invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

If you started the git daemon using TortoiseGit just use URL presented in the git.exe progress dialog: "git://10.192.20.140/", there is no need to specify a repository name or a branch name. If you want to clone a specific branch you have to enter this in the clone dialog (or add specific parameters to `git clone`).

`git clone git://10.192.20.140/`

Comment: Thanks. If you use `git clone git://10.192.20.140`,without the trailing `/`, it will return an error `fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax`.  I didn't notice until I saw this answer.