# TortoiseGit: cannot git clone in my local the daemonized branch from different machine

Tags: git, daemon, tortoisegit

When I try to clone a project, I got this exception in my terminal :

> git.exe clone --progress -v --depth 1
>   "git://10.192.20.204/dummy_project" "D:init/projects/dummy_project"
>   Cloning into 'D:init/projects/dummy_project'... fatal: read error:
>   Invalid argument fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commit is not accessible using TortoiseGit Daemon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536444/commit-is-not-accessible-using-tortoisegit-daemon)

Answer (score 0):

If you started the git daemon using TortoiseGit just use URL presented in the git.exe progress dialog: "git://10.192.20.204/", there is no need to specify a repository name or a branch name.

`git clone git://10.192.20.204/`